# Collection View reusable cell issue while scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uicollectionview, swift4

I am using the collection view to show the gif's on the list.
Now facing the cell reusable issue while scrolling the cells up or down of collection view.

Like **itemA** is on **first** place in the list and **itemB** is on the **second** place in the list.
but when I scroll the data in the collection view. the places of items got misplaced. like some time itemA gone on 5th place or sometimes anywhere in the list. 
i know i think this is the use with reusable cell, but don't know how to salve this.
Plss help.

**Collection view cellForItemAt**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GifCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? GifCell else {
        fatalError()
    }

    if gifArr.count > 0 {

        let urlString = self.gifArr[indexPath.row]
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
            let imageData3 = FLAnimatedImage(animatedGIFData: imageData) // this is the 3rd pary library to show the gifs on UIimageview's
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.imageView.animatedImage = imageData3
                cell.textLabel.text = String(indexPath.row)
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UICollection Cells are mixed in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58184741/uicollection-cells-are-mixed-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

In `GifCell` you could implement `prepareForReuse()` method:

> Performs any clean up necessary to prepare the view for use again.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    imageView.animatedImage = nil
    textLabel.text = ""
}
```

---

**Note**:
at this point, each time `cellForItemAt` method gets called, the url will be reloaded, so later, you might want find a way to cache the images instead of keep reloading them.

Answer (score 0):

**First solution**: You can cache data and every time check if there is, use your cache.
 you can use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44354779/5391914), but replace `UIImage` with gift type!

or 
try this, I did not test it

```
if let giftAny = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "giftUrl") {
  //cast giftAny to Data
  // use cached gift
} else {
  // cache gift
  let giftData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
  UserDefaults.standard.setValue(giftData, forKeyPath: "giftUrl")
  //use gift
}
```

**Second Solution**: Don't reuse cell

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = UICollectionViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier:"Cell")
        return cell
    }
```

but in this case, if you have many cells, memory leak is unavoidable.

Comment: Please can you tell how to cache data of gifs.

Comment: What is the type of `FLAnimatedImage(animatedGIFData: imageData)`?